# joomla wishlist and junk list integration

Tags: joomla

I am new with Joomla. I'm using Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart. Now I want to integrate the wishlist and junklist in Joomla 1.5 . Shall I get any free modules or component for it? If so please refer me. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow isn't really the place for extension recommendations. From doing a 5 second search, I found this:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-related-products/8149

However it's not free.

Here you can see the price list, the cheapest being at 39 euros.

http://www.vmwishlist.com/slice/buy-it/